# How to get a list of numbers which are greater than a certain number from a list?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list as follows:

```
number_list = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7).
```

I want to get a list which contain elements greater than 3. It should be something like this.

```
new_list =  (4, 5, 6, 7)
```

I can do something like foreach, to check every elements until it is smaller than 3. But is there other way to do that? Or some List methods to do it?

Comment: you could use linq: `var newList = list.Where(x=> x >3).ToList();`

Comment: If you want in output _"(4, 5, 6, 7)"_, why you want to loop and check _" until element smaller than 3"_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is `FindAll` which returns a `List`

```
List<int> items = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
items = items.FindAll(x => x < 3);
```

another way is `Where` combined with `ToList`

```
List<int> items = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
items = items.Where(x => x < 3).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried *Linq* and [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8)

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

```
var results = number_list.Where(x => x > someAwesomeNumber)
```

Comment: Or `FindAll(x=>x>number);`.